# My installed apps is suddenly stopped in emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image-processing, android-emulator

im doing my project convert image to black and white. the code has no error and already installed in virtual device.when the apps started, it suddenly stopped. i dont know whats problem. i have no experience in android programming.these are the codes.

these are the codes:

```
   package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    ImageView orginalImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    ImageView blackImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blackimage);

    Bitmap input = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.input);

    orginalImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(input));
    blackImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(
            convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(input)));
 }

   private Bitmap convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(Bitmap orginalBitmap) {
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);

    ColorMatrixColorFilter colorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
            colorMatrix);

    Bitmap blackAndWhiteBitmap = orginalBitmap.copy(
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(colorMatrixFilter);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(blackAndWhiteBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(blackAndWhiteBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    return blackAndWhiteBitmap;
  }
  }
```

Here is the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp" android:id="@+id/image" />
<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp" android:id="@+id/blackimage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat :

```
03-15 10:45:22.020: D/(1177): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection                 established 0xb7651388, tid 1177
03-15 10:45:22.330: W/EGL_emulation(1177): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 10:45:22.380: D/OpenGLRenderer(1177): Enabling debug mode 0
03-15 10:45:25.700: D/AndroidRuntime(1177): Shutting down VM
03-15 10:45:25.700: W/dalvikvm(1177): threadid=1: thread exiting with  uncaught exception (group=0xb2a16ba8)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177): Process: com.example.test, PID:  1177
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-15 10:45:25.820: E/AndroidRuntime(1177):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 10:45:31.050: I/Process(1177): Sending signal. PID: 1177 SIG: 9
```

Comment: logcat >> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity2}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: ok i didnt declare yet. may i know how to put in android manifest?

Comment: **have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

Comment: If you have no experience in android, may I suggest reading some documentation and actually try to make an effort first?http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1):

Following the logcat, you haven't declared your activity inside your manifest so go in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and add a reference to the activity:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity2"
   android:label="@string/app_name"> <!-- your app name -->
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter> <!-- this intent filter has to be placed in the activity you want as launch activity (the 1st one pratically)-->
</activity>
```